# In Vim, how to conceal ends or contained or ends+contained?

Tags: vim

I have the following text with variants which I enclose in ≤ and ≥ delimiters

```
The weather is beautiful ≤fair≥
Some text
Vim is hard to master ≤no variant…≥
```

I know how to hide the delimiters/ends (I found that solution elsewhere) and highlight the variants :

```
set conceallevel=2
syntax match Ignore /\|/ contained conceal
highlight sExamplesInText ctermbg=white ctermfg=black
syntax match sExamplesInText /\_.\{-}/ contains=Ignore
```

But how am I supposed to proceed if :

- hyp.1 : I want to show the delimiters/ends and hide the variants ?
- hyp.2 : I want to hide both the delimiters/ends and the variants ?

Thanks in advance for your help